# Delete option was not there in android contact groups created by programmatically

Tags: android, contacts

There is no delete option in android phone contact group which i created by pragmatically. Please help me. I've no idea how to delete the contact group for phone. By default, there are 'Family', 'Friends' & 'Work' 3 group under the phone contact, for testing purpose, I've created a group called 'Test' and assign a contact for that group. The problem now is, I didn't see there is any option for me to delete this custom group. Any idea?

```
group="Test";

if (group != null) {

    String GroupId = getGroupId();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, GroupId)
            .build());

}

private String getGroupId()
{
    String GroupId = ifGroup(group);
    if (GroupId == null)
    {

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> opsGroup = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        opsGroup.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, group)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE, true)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED, true)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME, group)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE, group)
                .build());
        try
        {

            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, opsGroup);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return ifGroup(group);
}
//### Function return group id by Group Title
private String ifGroup(String $name)
{
    String selection = ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + "=? and " + ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { "0", "1" };
    Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int len = cursor.getCount();

    String GroupId = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE));

        if (title.equals(group))
        {
            GroupId = id;
            break;
        }

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    return GroupId;
}
```